# R Shiny - customisation options not working for tippy::with_tippy()

Tags: r, shiny, tippyjs

I am trying to position a tooltip to the right of a `textInput` using the `tippy` package, however, it isn't working:

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    with_tippy(textInput("input", "input with tooltip"), "Input text", placement = "right")
 ),
 server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

The `position = 'right'`, `arrow = 'true'` and `theme = 'light'` options also don't seem to be working.

I was wondering if this was a browser compatibility issue or if I'm missing some CSS dependencies on my end? I have tried running the app on `Chrome v82.0.4068.5`, `Firefox 73.0.1` and `Microsoft Edge 44.18362.449.0` to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't run because `with_tippy` is not a valid function.

The code below should properly show the position of the tooltip.  *Important to note:* the `tippy_this(elementId)` refers back to the `textInput(inputId)` named **THISinput** here for clarity.

Instead of actually wrapping the `textInput` in the `tippy_this`, we just refer back to the input with `elementId`.

```
library(shiny)
library(tippy)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    textInput(inputId = "THISinput", "input with tooltip"),
    tippy_this(elementId = "THISinput", tooltip = "Hovertext for 'THISinput' here", placement="right")
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {}
)
```

Comment: Thank you @TTS! The code in my post comes from the vignette on Git: https://github.com/JohnCoene/tippy/blob/master/R/tippy.R and `with_tippy` is what they use. It still shows up in the package and I wasn't aware of `tippy_this`. Thanks again :)